# How to save Rich Text Field value onchange or onblur in Classic?

Tags: apex, visualforce

There is a solution in Lightning [How to get on change events for lightning:inputRichText?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221227/how-to-get-on-change-events-for-lightninginputrichtext) but we are using a Visualforce page so I'm wondering if there is a workaround to do it in Classic? This is what I've doing now but it does not work

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:inputField value="{!Rich_Text__c}" onblur="Save()" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

This also did not work:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:inputField value="{!Rich_Text__c}" onchange="Save()" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm), DOM events do not fire for rich text fields for `apex:inputfield`.

Comment: that is true. I'm wondering if there's a way around it.